# Help re-applying after Uk visit visa refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-ties

[image]

My refusal letter states that I provide more information on where my monthly expenditure of £200 comes from, I though did explain in my application letter that I am a student and all my support comes from my uncle since he sponsors me throughout my university education. The monthly expenditure is what I use to get by as a student whilst in school. I got a letter of sponsorship from him explaining he will cover my costs.(bank statements included)  As I reapply what other
information or documents should I provide to satisfy the ECOs and what mistakes should I watch out for?

Comment: In addition to the linked (possible) duplicate, there are a lot of questions on this site about failed visa applications to attend a UK army assessment. Try finding and reading some of those.

Comment: @Taps Kay Did you include your own bank statements as well as those from your sponsor?

Comment: @traveller No I did not include my personal statement but Included my sponsors . Since I am a student I get that support of £200 per month from my uncle so yes that is my expenditure per month and not savings so I thought I didn’t have to include a statement.

Comment: @the road less travelled thanks for that link it’s been so helpful

Comment: @Taps Kay As you’ll see from the duplicate question, it’s essential that all applicants include their personal bank statements irrespective of whether they have a sponsor or not. In your case, it’s important that the two sets of statements prove an existing connection with your sponsor ie the statements should show payment of the £200pm by your sponsor to your account. This helps to satisfy V4.3(a) of the Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules by showing the ECO there is a genuine relationship with your sponsor

Comment: @traveller thanks so much helping enlighten me on this issue. I am very grateful  and I will proceed to reapply and most definitely put this in the application to show the connection.

Comment: The letter also asks you to explain the other twelve days of your visit.

Comment: @DJClayworth i did explain that in my cover letter but I stated that the army requires you arrive at least one week before to adjust to change in environments.. I stated I would be there for 14 days ..because the assessment is entirely the only reason I’m there do I indicate that  9 days is the exact time that I will spend there?